# How to retrieve from lat, lon value using pygrib

Tags: python, grib, pygrib

I'm starting in python programming and I would like to make a small script which displays the data of "Local temperature diagnosed at 2m height above the relief", "Zonal component of the west-east horizontal wind diagnosed at 10 m height" and the "Meridian component of the horizontal wind diagnosed at 10 m height" as a function of longitude and latitude.

For this, I download a file from the open data site of Meteofrance [OPEN DATA](https://donneespubliques.meteofrance.fr/?fond=produit&id_produit=131&id_rubrique=51) by selecting:

Domain: "France - 0.01 °", Sub Package: "SP1 - Current surface parameters", Deadline group "0h" and Run date "2020-02-10 00 UTC"

So I have a file in grib2 format that I am trying to process with the pygrib library

To start simple, I'm just trying to get the temperature for a given point (longitude = 0.25, latitude = 49.21)

I created an index to read the file (It seems that it is the fastest)

```
indx = pygrib.index('./AROME_0.01_SP1_00H_2020021000.grib2', 'typeOfLevel', 'level', 'name')
```

I select the records which correspond to the temperature and I recover the values:

```
msg = indx.select(level=2, typeOfLevel="heightAboveGround", name="2 metre temperature")
temp2m = msg[0].values
```

The problem is that from there, I fumble and I don't find how to retrieve from this variable (numpy.ma.core.MaskedArray) the value that corresponds to my longitude = 0.25 and latitude = 49.21

If someone has an idea, I'm interested

```
import pygrib
indx = pygrib.index('./AROME_0.01_SP1_00H_2020021000.grib2', 'typeOfLevel', 'level', 'name') 
msg = indx.select(level=2, typeOfLevel="heightAboveGround", name="2 metre temperature")
temp2m = msg[0].values
```

Comment: Maybe [this](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.generic.html#accessing-the-data) helps:

I.e. what is the output of `temp2m.data`?

Comment: Use cfgrib. It is state of the art and much easier to use.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the pygrib.data() method to create a bounding box around your lat/lon and then take the mean of the values within that box. Just adjust the tolerance to control how big the box is.

```
lat, lon, tolerence = 49.21, 0.25, 0.1
data, lats, lons = grb.data(lat1=lat-tolerence,lat2=lat+tolerence,
                            lon1=lon-tolerence,lon2=lon+tolerence)
data.mean()
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get your lat and lon by using `.latlons()` from your variable that you selected (not the values). From there you can get your index corresponding your point.

```
import pygrib
indx = pygrib.index('./AROME_0.01_SP1_00H_2020021000.grib2', 'typeOfLevel', 'level', 'name') 
msg = indx.select(level=2, typeOfLevel="heightAboveGround", name="2 metre temperature")

lat,lon = msg.latlons()

temp2m = msg[0].values
```